# fs.readdirSync directories first

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I want to read a directory from my system. The directory structure is

[image: dir]

I read the directory with this code

```
const directoryLevelInfo = fs.readdirSync('data', 'utf8')
                        .map(item => {
                            const path = `data/${item}`;

                            const isDir = fs.lstatSync(path)
                                             .isDirectory();

                            return {
                                name: item,
                                path: path,
                                isDir: isDir
                            };
                        });
```

and the result I get is

```
[ { name: 'FileOne.md', path: 'data/FileOne.md', isDir: false },
  { name: 'FolderOne', path: 'data/FolderOne', isDir: true },
  { name: 'FolderTwo', path: 'data/FolderTwo', isDir: true } ]
```

As you can see the file comes first and after that I get the folders. The correct order would be orders first, files last.

Am I missing something or do I have to use

`Array.sort()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

to order this structure correctly? And how would you order it because you have to check if the current item is a file or directory and if you compare two items of the same type you have to order them alphabetically too.

---

**EDIT:**

My sort function would be

```
                        .sort((a, b) => {
                            if (!a.isDir && b.isDir) {
                                return 1;
                            }

                            if (a.isDir && !b.isDir) {
                                return -1;
                            }

                            if (a.isDir && b.isDir || !a.isDir && !b.isDir) {
                                return 0;
                            }
                        });
```

Maybe there are some improvements for this.

Comment: Why not `.sort()` after `.map` ?

Comment: do you think I have to sort it?

Comment: Yes sort by `isDir` property

Comment: I added my sort function, do you think it's fine or do you think I can optimize it?

Comment: You could use `(a, b) => { (b.isDir ? 1 : 0) - (a.isDir ? 1 : 0) }`

Comment: How about this https://jsbin.com/jegaxuwame/edit?js ?

Comment: You could simply use `(a, b) => b.isDir - a.isDir`.

Comment: @dereli will these bools get converted to numbers automatically?

Comment: yes, they will. subtraction operator will call ToNumber on operands and for boolean values it's either 1 or +0 for true and false respectively. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2

Answer (score 2):

Node.js `fs.readdir` and `fs.readdirSync` functions behave [inconsistently](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3232) in terms of sorting and they also differ on Windows vs *nix. If you need persistent behaviour it seems your best bet is to sort after mapping.

Assuming you want to sort directories and files alphabetically, you can use the following code.

```
const directoryLevelInfo = fs
  .readdirSync("documentation", "utf8")
  .map(item => {
    const path = `documentation/${item}`;

    const isDir = fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory();

    return {
      name: item,
      path: path,
      isDir: isDir
    };
  })
  .sort((a, b) => b.isDir - a.isDir || a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: For me it was working with the following sort function: `.sort((a, b) => b.isDir - a.isDir || a.name - b.name)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareFiles(a,b) {
    return b.isDirectory() - a.isDirectory() || a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1
  }
```

I adapted @dereli's answer because I use fs.readdir differently: I added the option {withFileTypes: true} so that the files returned by fs.readdir are fs.dirent
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback
and they already have then method isDirectory()

```
fs.readdir(currentDir, { withFileTypes: true }, function (err, items) {
    items.sort(compareFiles);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (!items[i].name.startsWith(".")) {
            if (items[i].isFile()) {
               //append file name somewhere
            } else {
               //append directory name somewhere
            }
        }
    }
});
```

it might help someone one day...